# How to view compile errors in all files in Xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

When I'm compiling a project in Xcode 4, compilation stops as soon as errors encountered in any of the code files. Sometimes I want to compile all code files in project and view all errors at once. Is that possible? Am I missing a setting for this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In the Xcode's Preference, in the General Tab, check the "Continue building after errors" option, as shown in the image below

[image: Xcode General Preferences]