# xcodebuild doesn't show all compile errors?

Tags: ios, compilation, xcodebuild

There are 2 compile errors in my project(Display in XCode).

But when I use xcodebuild to compile the project in terminal, only one compile error display

```
xxx$xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug
....
....
[self updateAccountInfo];1
                         ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Is it possible to make xcodebuild display all compile errors?

In the Xcode's Preference, in the General Tab, check the "Continue building after errors" option. [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930004/how-to-view-compile-errors-in-all-files-in-xcode-4)

What I need is to use xcodebuild do the same thing.

**EDIT:**

After thinking and researching these days, I think xcodebuild can't do this. It's different from xcode. When we use xcode to compile iOS project, xcode compile every .m by clang. So xcode has "Continue building after errors" feature

Comment: Try using the `clang` flag `-ferror-limit=0` (just guessing tho).

Comment: @trojanfoe I just try "-xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug OTHER_CFLAGS="-ferror-limit=0"",it isn't work.

Comment: OK, how about running `defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXBuildsContinueAfterErrors YES`?

Comment: @trojanfoe "PBXBuildsContinueAfterErrors" works for me. Thank you so much, this is really what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the Xcode preferences to do this (from `Terminal.app`):

```
$ defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXBuildsContinueAfterErrors YES
```

for xCode 8:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEBuildingContinueBuildingAfterErrors 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I use "xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug PBXBuildsContinueAfterErrors=YES" to do this.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to continue building after errors using the latest version of xcodebuild/xctool you will need to run them with `-IDEBuildingContinueBuildingAfterErrors=YES`.

Example:

```
xctool -project SampleProject.xcodeproj/ -scheme SampleProject -sdk iphonesimulator build -IDEBuildingContinueBuildingAfterErrors=YES
```

Looks like `PBXBuildsContinueAfterErrors` isn't supported anymore.

Also you can use `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode` to make this setting permanent. If you want to have a look how you current version of IDE is controlling that setting you can call `defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode` and search for "errors" and "continue".

Comment: Thank you. But what I need is show all compile errors in one compile. And after deep thinking, I think it is a mission impossible.  Assuming that ClassA depend ClassB, now both ClassA and ClassB have compile errors, the compiler can only show errors in ClassB. Right?